# Expo cli or React native cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a lot of react development experience and just learnt React Native. I’m developing a mobile app. This app will have those functions:
Login system(including face id and finger print login);
Using camera to take pics and uploading to account;
Uploading pdf,doc,xml… files;
Group people can chat, send message, talk and video call like zoom(maybe embed zoom sdk)
I am using React Native cli. But it’s very painful on setting in android and ios. And gave me a lot of errors. I’m not good at Java and Xcode. It’s really painful for me on all kinds of settings, Xcode version issues, etc. So I just want to know if I switch to expo cli, can all functions I list above be implemented by expo? Scary to have to eject in the future.

Thank you very much for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do almost everything.
Look at this, https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/q7xpxo/create_video_chat_application_using_expo/

here are some useful links for the other tools you need

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/  -- mentions of expo-camera expo-contacts. You just have to be aware of compatibilities between versions.

https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/sharing/  -- to pick an image from phone and share it.

and this last to implement face-id
https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-react-native-biometric-authentication-expo/

the video call and chat that is something that can be done in expo but I'm not sure about the performance, I would look for examples of chat apps developed with expo. As was mentioned in the reddit link, the bridge could bring some performance issues so they decide to move that part to the native side.

Comment: Thank you very much for you great advice and help!

Comment: I would start with the **managed workflow**, and when I need a native module to be added I would run ```expo eject``` and then I would be in the **bare workflow** of expo, that means I would need to have the environment prepared with xcode and android studio, sorry for that.   
this link needs to be in bare-workflow (is just naming to say you are in react-native mode, no more expo controlling your app, is just on you, but expo still can help you with some modules, and settings) 
https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-react-native-biometric-authentication-expo/